# Remove SSL from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, ssl

I installed a Sharepoint site with https:// a while ago, but because of new company policies we have to remove this feature. What I did so far:

- Created a new binding in IIS on port 80
- Create a Alternate Access Mapping with the Sharepoint admin on port 80

The homepage seems to load fine without https. Also individual pages are available on port 80. The issue is that when you click on a link on any page it redirects back to https. Please note that the links on the pages are not hard coded to use https.

Comment: Are you using any rewrite rule in IIS? Is https still the default zone? Do you have any entries in AAM that still points to https?

Comment: @user19952 https is still there but I can't delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably because of a misconfigured AAM.
If you want to completely remove HTTPS access, simply edit AAM with only one public URL (for the default zone): the HTTP one.

Comment: @Everiste after removing the HTTPS access I receive "something went wrong" on every page.

Comment: After editing the default zone AAM, I've seen cases where an IISRESET was needed. If both IIS binding and AAM only define HTTP, I don't see why it would lead to such an error.

Comment: ISSreset was needed, indeed.